# i cant access my element with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I want to access my button on the page but when I click on the button nothing happens

Please guide me

```css
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cart_inside').load('php/load_Cart.php',function(e){
    $('.add_to_cart').click(function(e) {
      var id = $(this).next().val();
      $.post("php/cart_add.php", {
        id: id
      }, function(e) {
        $('#cart_inside').append("<span>" + e + "</span><button></button>");
      });
    });

    $('button').click(function(e){
      alert('hi');
    });     
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <div id="cart_inside"></div>
  <a href="php/cart_remove_all.php">empty cart</a>
  <div id="buy">
    <a href="final_cart.php">cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cart_inside').append("<button>button</button>");
    $('#cart_inside').on('click', 'button', function(){
      alert('hi');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cart_inside'></div>
```